# fill jquery datatable with Json array MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

i got a view with a jquery datatable, i want on a single button to repopulate the data from the table instantly with another Json list or whatever array he received from the controller.

This is the code in my view :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "EmpTruck/getJson/",
    data: { search: station },
    dataType: "Json",
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    success: function (json) {

        alert(json.aaData);
        var table = $(".dynamicTableEmployee").dataTable();
        table.fnClearTable();
        table.LoadDataRow(json);
    }
});
```

This is the code from controller :

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult getJson()
{

    List<Employees> list = new List<Employees>();
    list = db.Employees.Where(c => c.Station.Equals("ATL")).ToList();


    return this.Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}

This code only clear the datatable.
I have set a breakpoint to see if there is something in the Json array and there is.

I don't know how to populate the datatable from the json array, do i need to serialize it ? Do the json need to be the same size as the datatable?

Thanks

Comment: can you add your code to jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to reload the data you can use the fnReloadAjax() API plug-in: http://datatables.net/plug-ins#api_fnReloadAjax

If you want to completely alter the table like change columns etc... I'd just nuke the old one and replace it with the new. Just paste the code into your script (before you initialise you table!), then whenever you want to reload the data, call fnReloadAjax() on the table object.

This example might help: http://datatables.net/examples/example_plugin_api.html

---

(from http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/52/load-new-data-via-ajax/p1)

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Table.css")" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" />
  @section scripts
  {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ datatable.js")"   type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/test.js")" type="text/javascript">  </script>
  }
   <div id="tabs-SecDeal" style=" background-color: white">
    <table id="secdeal" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="background-color: #990033">col1</th>
                <th style="background-color: #990033"> col2</th>
                <th style="background-color: #990033"> col3 </th>
                <th style="background-color: #990033"> col4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="dataTables_empty"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

```html
$(function () {
         Loadtestview();
    function Loadtestview () {
        var divSecTable = $('#secdeal');
            oSecTable = divSecTable.dataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "aaSorting": [1, 'asc'],
                "info": true,//localtable.bInfo,
                "autoWidth": false,//localtable.AutoWidth,            
                "scrollY": 700,
                "scrollX": "150%",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                'destroy': true,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                'lengthChange': false,
                "searching": false,
                'sAjaxSource': '../ReportsMvc/GetSecuritizationDeal',
                "iDisplayLength": 100,
                "columns": [
{ "targets": 0,"data":"col1","title":"col1", "className": "center textNoWrap" },
{ "targets": 1,"data":"col2","title":"col2", "className": "center textNoWrap" },
{ "targets": 2,"data":"col3","title":"col3", "className": "center textNoWrap" },
{ "targets": 3,"data":"col4","title":"col4", "className": "center textNoWrap" },
                ],

                'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {       
                      aoData.push({ "name": "rgid", "value": $("#ddlBatchdate").val() });
                    $.get(sSource, aoData, function (rsp) {
                        fnCallback(rsp);
                    });
                },
                "fnInitComplete": function () {
                    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(oSecTable, { leftColumns: 4 });       
                }
            });
    }
});
```

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetSecuritizationDeal(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        if (param.rgid <= 0)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                sEcho = "1",
                iTotalRecords = 0,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = 0,
                aaData = (IEnumerable<SecDealDatacs>)new List<SecDealDatacs>()
            },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        try
        {
            //No session cache for reports page!!!
            List<SecDealDatacs> listObj =   _bao.GetSecuritizationDeal(param.rgid);
            if (listObj == null)
                throw new HttpException(500, "Data Server Errors...");
            int totalRecords = listObj.Count();
            //Pagenation            
            IEnumerable<SecDealDatacs> listObjDisplay = listObj
                .Skip(param.iDisplayStart)
                .Take(param.iDisplayLength);


            var result = listObjDisplay.Select((o, index) => new
            {
                o.col1,
                o.col2,
               col3= o.col3.ToString("#,#"),
                col4=o. col4.ToString("0.0000"),
            }).ToList();

            var listObj1 = result;

            return Json(new
            {
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = totalRecords,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = totalRecords,
                aaData = result
            },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log error into DB and File
            throw new HttpException(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$(function () {
         Loadtestview();
    function Loadtestview () {
        var divSecTable = $('#secdeal');
            oSecTable = divSecTable.dataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "aaSorting": [1, 'asc'],
                "info": true,//localtable.bInfo,
                "autoWidth": false,//localtable.AutoWidth,            
                "scrollY": 700,
                "scrollX": "150%",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                'destroy': true,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                'lengthChange': false,
                "searching": false,
                'sAjaxSource': '../ReportsMvc/GetSecuritizationDeal',
                "iDisplayLength": 100,
                "columns": [
{ "targets": 0,"data":"col1","title":"col1", "className": "center textNoWrap" },
{ "targets": 1,"data":"col2","title":"col2", "className": "center textNoWrap" },
{ "targets": 2,"data":"col3","title":"col3", "className": "center textNoWrap" },
{ "targets": 3,"data":"col4","title":"col4", "className": "center textNoWrap" },
                ],

                'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {       
                      aoData.push({ "name": "rgid", "value": $("#ddlBatchdate").val() });
                    $.get(sSource, aoData, function (rsp) {
                        fnCallback(rsp);
                    });
                },
                "fnInitComplete": function () {
                    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(oSecTable, { leftColumns: 4 });       
                }
            });
    }
});
```